# FFMPEG - Convert MKV to MP4 with all streams (subtitles) and watermark

Tags: video, ffmpeg, converters, mp4, mkv

I spent few hours researching and still have problem...
I want to convert .mkv file to .mp4 with watermark and subtitles (from mkv).

I tried few commands but always error or success with watermark **without subtitles**.
Here are some commands I tried (not all):

**Partial Success - some files are converted with subtitles, but I have 153 files that are converted without subtitles... (both from .mkv to .mp4):**

```
ffmpeg -i 025.mkv -vf "movie=logovideo2.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,subtitles=025.mkv [out]" 25.mp4

ffmpeg -i 001.mkv -i logovideo2.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0,subtitles=001.mkv[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:s ass 001.mp4
```

**Fail - command with error:**

```
ffmpeg -i 001.mkv -i logovideo2.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -map 0:s -c:s ass 001.mp4
```

**CODE (with error):**

```
ffmpeg version N-81036-g2b14204 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libass
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 50.100 / 57. 50.100
  libavformat    57. 42.100 / 57. 42.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '001.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : DB
    encoder         : libebml v1.2.1 + libmatroska v1.1.1
    creation_time   : 2011-09-15 16:44:37
  Duration: 00:24:39.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1429 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(jpn): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 720x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:2(pol): Subtitle: ass (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Grupa
Input #1, png_pipe, from 'logovideo2.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 235x50 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 47:10], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File '001.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[libx264 @ 0x43c7a80] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x43c7a80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x43c7a80] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x43c7a80] 264 - core 148 r2 3f5ed56 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=23 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
**[mp4 @ 0x442c9e0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[mp4 @ 0x442c9e0] Could not find tag for codec ass in stream #2, codec not currently supported in container**
Output #0, mp4, to '001.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : DB
    encoder         : Lavf57.42.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 720x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.50.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.50.100 aac
    Stream #0:2(pol): Subtitle: ass (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Grupa
      encoder         : Lavc57.50.100 ass
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (vorbis (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (ass (ssa) -> ass (native))
**Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument**
[aac @ 0x43bf600] Qavg: -nan
```

Comment: The 2nd command should work. Is the fontfile referenced in the ASS stream valid? Run `ffmpeg -i 001.mkv -c:s copy -map 0:s 001.ass` and check the file.

Comment: @Mulvya -  yeah...it works... so how to split this command with watermark etc. ?

Comment: Split command? Don't follow.

Comment: @Mulvya command `ffmpeg -i 001.mkv -i logovideo2.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:s copy -map 0:s 001.mp4` still has error. `[mp4 @ 0x49fb480] Could not find tag for codec ass in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container` and `Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument`

Comment: That's the 3rd command. You can't mux a ASS file into a MP4. Use `-c:s mov_text` if you want it as a separate stream.

Comment: @Mulvya - `ffmpeg -i 001.mkv -i logovideo2.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0,subtitles=001.mkv[out]" -map "[out]" -c:s copy -map 0:s -map 0:a 001.mp4` still has errors... ;/ like in my comment above.

Comment: And I forgot to tell you about that some files works with this command `ffmpeg -i 025.mkv -vf "movie=logovideo2.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,subtitles=025.mkv [out]" 25.mp4` in .mp4 shows subtitles, but I have 153 videos in .mkv that doesn't work... converted to .mp4 without subtitles. Why?

Comment: If you wish to use `-map 0:s` then `-c:s` should be `mov_text`, not `copy`.

Comment: @Mulvya - I want this subtitles hardcoded in .mp4 not different stream because in hostings like openload.co it doesn't work (subtitles). Just tell me how to do this... I don't know all that commands which I tested they're exactly what I want :D lol.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i 001.mkv -i logovideo2.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0,subtitles=001.mkv[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a 001.mp4`

Comment: @Mulvya yeah it should work but it doesn't... input: `Duration: 00:24:39.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1429 kb/s
Stream #0:0(jpn): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 720x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
Stream #0:2(pol): Subtitle: ass (default)
Metadata:
title: Grupa` OUTPUT `Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
  subtitles (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (vorbis (native) -> aac (native))` ...

Comment: Show the full console output. Paste it into the Q.

Comment: @Mulvya to the comment above rest of output `Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: aac (LC)` so as you can see it doesn't pick subtitles I don't know why... in other files it works but in this 153 files is shit like this...

Comment: @Mulvya ok I replied in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2024 Update - SOLUTION:** Command was working, but didn't worked on my server because I didn't have any fonts installed lol... so I had to install fonts and then it worked... :D

Command `ffmpeg -i 001.mkv -i logovideo2.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0,subtitles=001.mkv[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a 001.mp4`

Doesn't has subtitles... here's output:

```
ffmpeg version N-81036-g2b14204 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libass
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 50.100 / 57. 50.100
  libavformat    57. 42.100 / 57. 42.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '001.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : Dragon Ball #1
    encoder         : libebml v1.2.1 + libmatroska v1.1.1
    creation_time   : 2011-09-15 16:44:37
  Duration: 00:24:39.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1429 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(jpn): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 720x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:2(pol): Subtitle: ass (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Grupa
Input #1, png_pipe, from 'logovideo2.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 235x50 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 47:10], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[Parsed_subtitles_1 @ 0x459aaa0] Shaper: FriBidi 0.19.4 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 0.9.36 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_subtitles_1 @ 0x459aaa0] Using font provider fontconfig
File '001_Dragon_Ball_NapisyPL.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[Parsed_subtitles_1 @ 0x4542f80] Shaper: FriBidi 0.19.4 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 0.9.36 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_subtitles_1 @ 0x4542f80] Using font provider fontconfig
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] 264 - core 148 r2 3f5ed56 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=23 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[mp4 @ 0x453ad80] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Output #0, mp4, to '001.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : Dragon Ball #1
    encoder         : Lavf57.42.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 720x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.50.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.50.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
  subtitles (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (vorbis (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=34743 fps=108 q=-1.0 Lsize=  150041kB time=00:24:39.38 bitrate= 830.8kbits/s speed=4.59x    
video:125218kB audio:23557kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.851010%
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] frame I:340   Avg QP:19.82  size: 38155
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] frame P:13109 Avg QP:22.20  size:  6213
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] frame B:21294 Avg QP:25.43  size:  1588
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] consecutive B-frames: 14.3%  9.7%  7.2% 68.9%
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] mb I  I16..4:  4.2% 61.7% 34.0%
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] mb P  I16..4:  1.9%  7.1%  2.0%  P16..4: 38.2% 12.2%  7.9%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:30.5%
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.8%  0.3%  B16..8: 34.2%  2.9%  0.5%  direct: 1.4%  skip:59.6%  L0:45.0% L1:52.1% BI: 2.9%
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] 8x8 transform intra:63.3% inter:77.4%
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 55.9% 74.8% 36.6% inter: 10.9% 18.1% 1.0%
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 39% 24% 13% 24%
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 17% 27%  5%  5%  6%  5%  5%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 27% 20% 14%  6%  7%  8%  6%  6%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 48% 24% 22%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:5.3% UV:1.0%
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] ref P L0: 65.0% 13.3% 15.4%  6.1%  0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] ref B L0: 89.1%  8.4%  2.5%
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] ref B L1: 97.2%  2.8%
[libx264 @ 0x44fe7a0] kb/s:707.89
[aac @ 0x45939e0] Qavg: 654.550
```

Comment: Looks like the subtitle file is not valid. There should be a line like this: `[Parsed_subtitles_1 @ 00000000004cdfc0] fontselect: (Arial, 400, 0) -> Arial, 0, (none)`. Extract the subtitle using the command in my 1st comment and upload it.

Comment: @Mulvya hmmm I extracted all .ass files and then did my first and second command with subtitles=file.ass or ass=file.ass but still no subtitles in video, wtf? ;/

Comment: There's `[Parsed_ass_0 @ 0x36499a0] Added subtitle file: '001.ass' (5 styles, 288 events)` but in the end `Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (vorbis (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 5845 fps=101 q=-1.0 Lsize=   28237kB time=00:04:04.20 bitrate= 947.2kbits/s speed=4.21x    
video:24177kB audio:3851kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.746255%` ;/

Comment: Upload one of these subtitles.

Comment: http://skroc.pl/c932b - it shows everything in .mp4 after convert except 2 first lines :P

Comment: @Mulvya, and? Did you figure it out? :D Because I have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: Both subtitle files burn correctly here. I suggest using a static [binary](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) from Zeranoe and trying.

Comment: I'm using CentOS 7 in this case, so... I guess everything should be fine... maybe I'll try on my Debian later.

Comment: @Mulvya - nope...on my Debian still doesn't work. I don't get it!

Comment: I think you need a build with fontconfig enabled.

Comment: @Mulvya - on my dekstop I have some error with this command `ffmpeg -i 001.mp4 -vf ass=001.ass 001.mp4` on server (centos) I didn't have it. It's `[h264 @ 0x14db720] AVC: nal size 2210
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x14db720] no frame!
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xa94e60] stream 1, offset 0x839a: partial file
001.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input` What does it mean?

Comment: FFmpeg can't parse the video stream Which version? Weren't you working with MKV?

Comment: @Mulvya - ups I didn't see it's .mp4 not .mkv haha my fault :D now I did on my computer `ffmpeg -i 001.mkv -vf ass=001.ass 001.mp4` and there's subtitles...hmmm...  ffmpeg on my computer `ffmpeg version 3.0.2-4~bpo8+1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers` and enabled everything, on my server I have enabled just what I wanted :P

Comment: This `ffmpeg -i 001.mkv -i logovideo2.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0,subtitles=001.mkv[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:s ass 001.mp4` works too on my computer...

Comment: Ouch I forgot write a reply... command above works, but didn't worked on my server because I didn't have any fonts installed lol... so I had to install fonts and then it worked... and still works till now :D